# Can you help me to explain a subquery as a column in sql ? codeacademy table transformation

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT origin, id,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM flights f
WHERE f.id < flights.id
AND f.origin=flights.origin) + 1
AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights;
```

> CodeAcademy Learn about:
>   It would also be interesting to order flights by giving them a ***sequence number*** based on time, by carrier.
>   For instance, assuming flight_id increments with each additional flight, we could use the following query to view flights by carrier, flight id, and sequence number:

i dont understand about this code means. i got this code from learning in codeacademy, SQL Table Transformation Module..
this 1 makes me confuse.. anybody can help me to explain that code ? 
in where condition f id less than flights id, but they come from the same table and value. :S

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTf8b.png)

Answer (score 0):

First let's understand the inner query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM flights f
WHERE f.id < flights.id
AND f.origin=flights.origin
```

In above query f.id is for the table we're referencing in the sub query where as flights.id is for the outer query.

As both the keys are from same table, we're comparing it within same table only.

**Basically entire SQL query is finding result for each row with value of id less then the row's *(row which is being compared)* id and of the same carrier.**

Let's take example of the first row from the example image you've given.

**Table : flights**
===============
**Carrier  |  ID**

MQ          17107
===============

So, the SQL query will find all the rows within **flights table** whose 
 `id` is less than **17107** and `carrier` is equal to **MQ**.

Motive of the entire query is to get the sequence number of the flight 
**assuming** flight_id increments with each additional flight.

Answer (score 0):

It is counting all the flights going to the same destination whose ID is **less than** the current ID being queried and then adding one to get the flight sequence number.